# ViewPager.setPageMargin() incorrectly positioning page

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

After calling setPageMargin(margin) on a ViewPager instance the current fragment (or page) isn't repositioned correctly.

I would expect the left and right should look exactly the same after the setPageMargin() call.
[image: Images of pageMargin 0 and after setPageMargin(100)]

MainActivity onCreate():

```
pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
pager.setAdapter(new FragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()) {
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                return BlankFragment.newInstance("Hello " + position, "Test");
            }
            public int getCount() {
                return 200;
            }
        });
```

MainActivity onOptionsItemSelected() for the Toggle button:

```
int margin;
if (toggleState) {
    margin = 0;
    toggleState = false;
} else {
    margin = 100;
    toggleState = true;
}
pager.setPageMargin(margin);
```

A bug?

Comment: you're talking about that between pages is doubled space, right?

Comment: @piotrek1543 The margin is for the space in between the pages [ViewPager.setPageMargin()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setPageMargin(int)). The problem is, once I change the page margin to what I want (e.g. 100) it doesn't reposition it to the page it was on previously (the page with "Hello 7").